# mysql error in query for timestamp interval

Tags: php, mysql

I have voting_IP table as follow:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ip_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mes_id_fk | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ip_add    | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to run this query which has errors and I don't know how to correct it?

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip' and timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR);)");
```

I also tried this one:

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where (mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip' and timestamp > (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR);))");
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks,but mysql_query is still working

Comment: It is. Just like horse and wagon is still working.

Comment: :D ok,yes I studied,as sure I will change it,Thanks Buddy

Comment: it is true that it is working, but your code is vulnerable to injection (especially if you're not escaping $id et al beforehand) and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INTERVAL -1 HOUR);))");
                 ^-----here is the error extra semicolon
```

you can see the error by `mysql_query("your query ") or die(mysql_error())`

Replace by :

```
INTERVAL -1 HOUR))");
```

Comment: @nikparsa  could  you tell what error message are you getting ?

Comment: `INTERVAL -1 HOUR))");` should work (one more `)` to remove)

Comment: I can't it goes behind my html design I just see some of them:you have error in your sql syntax

Comment: @nikparsa yes ,could you show the complete message ?

Comment: If I could I would tell but it will go behind the whole how Can I make it go more below?

Comment: @nikparsa try `die('<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>'.mysql_error())`

Comment: the error was because of something else Thanks it is now working